# Not using constexpr in c++ template arguments

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, constexpr, itk

I am working with a variable of type `itk::Image<OutputPixelType, Dimension>`, where "itk" comes from the image processing library ITK.

The following code compiles:

```
constexpr unsigned int Dimension = 3;
using PixelType = float; 
using MyImageType = itk::Image<PixelType, Dimension>;
```

But now I need to define "Dimension" as something computed from a function.

```
unsigned int Dimension = get_dimension(...);
```

My compiler gives an error:

```
error: non-type template argument is not a constant expression
  using MyImageType = itk::Image<PixelType, Dimension>;
                                            ^~~~~~~~~
```

How could I work around this issue? I hope to use "Dimension" as something computed from a function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `get_dimension` function should be `constexpr` and, if that is the case, you can have the following:

```cpp
constexpr unsigned int Dimension = get_dimension(...);
```

**Example**

Let's say you have the following simplified class:

```cpp
template <int v>
class Foo {
public:
    constexpr Foo()
        : v_(v)
    {}

private:
    int v_;
};
```

and then the following:

```cpp
int v = get();
using FooInt = Foo<v>;
```

where `get` function is defined as follows:

```cpp
int get() {
    return 1;
}
```

You will get the same as error as you are getting in your example.

Therefore, the **solution** would be to mark `get` function `constexpr` and make the `v` value also `constexpr` like:

```cpp
constexpr int get() {
    return 1;
}

constexpr int v = get();
using FooInt = Foo<v>;
```

Take a look at the [demo](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:3,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:23,endLineNumber:19,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:18,selectionStartColumn:23,selectionStartLineNumber:19,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:18),source:'%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%0Aconstexpr+int+get()+%7B%0A++++return+1%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Atemplate+%3Cint+v%3E%0Aclass+Foo+%7B%0Apublic:%0A++++constexpr+Foo()%0A++++++++:+v_(v)%0A++++%7B%7D%0A%0Aprivate:%0A++++int+v_%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aconstexpr+int+v+%3D+get()%3B%0Ausing+FooInt+%3D+Foo%3Cv%3E%3B%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%233',t:'0')),header:(),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:gsnapshot,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'0',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B11',selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:3),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Editor+%233,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:33.33333333333333,l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:3,fontScale:14,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:50,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)

**UPDATE**

In order to be able to use templates, compiler needs to know template parameters at compile time, and therefore, if `Dimension` is not a `constexpr` (which declares that it is possible to evaluate the value of the variable at compile time) variable, it cannot be used as template parameter.

Comment: maybe worth mentioning that if `Dimension` is not `constexpr` it cannot be used as template parameter.

Comment: @idclev463035818 yep, that's worth of mentioning

Comment: i just noticed that the quesiton title can be misread as OP not wanting to use `constexpr` but from the question it is more or less clear that the confusion is from `constexpr` variable vs `constexpr` function and your answer nicely explains that